# mongoid test db queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

to improve performance I want to aassert which queries are being run. I tried implementing the [command monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/monitoring/#command-monitoring) but it didn't seem to do anything, i.e. put `binding.pry` in the `started` events didn't catch anything.

What am I missing here?